# What is the minimal block time practically possible?

Tags: altcoin-development, block-interval

There have been so many altcoins that experimented with parameters like block-time, and I was wondering what turned out to be the minimal feasible time?

If its 10 seconds for example, there will be so many orphans that the network will not function. So it cannot be too short, but how short can it be for a reasonably functioning network?